# "substr_count" не срабатывает с латиницей

Tags: php

```
$url = "http://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt";
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
echo strtolower($contents), '<br>';
echo substr_count($contents, 'user-agent');
```

Таким кодом пытаюсь получить кол-во директив "user-agent", мне выдаёт - 0
Что не так подскажите

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы забыли перевести все в нижний регистр

```
$url = "http://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt";
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
$contents = strtolower($contents);
echo $contents, '<br>';
echo substr_count($contents, 'user-agent');
```

Comment: Ну или нормально писать `User-Agent`

Comment: $url = "http://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt";
    $contents = null;
    $contents = file_get_contents($url);
    echo substr_count(strtolower($content), 'user-agent');

Такое выдаёт - 0